# Confront and update values between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames, the first one contains customer transactions of an online store

```
ItemCode    Invoice    Quantity    Date       UnitPrice    CustomerID
1234        1111       12          12/11/04   12.90        70829
3342        1134       2           14/12/04   5.00         70562
2345        1231       5           21/12/04   8.99         71233
```

The second one contains only the deleted transactions of the store

```
ItemCode    Invoice    Quantity    Date       UnitPrice    CustomerID
3342        NA         -2          14/12/04   5.00         70562
1345        NA         -10         27/02/05   1.99         81728
2345        NA         -1          22/12/04   8.99         71233
```

I would like to update the first dataframe with the actual purchases of each customer, e.g.:

```
ItemCode    Invoice    Quantity    Date       UnitPrice    CustomerID
1234        1111       12          12/11/04   12.90        70829
3342        1134       0           14/12/04   5.00         70562
2345        1231       4           21/12/04   8.99         71233
```

I think that I may have to write a user defined function, with a loop which confronts for every rows in the deleted transactions dataframe the CustomerID and the ItemCode, and then update the quantity value in the first dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

If a `CustomerID` can only be linked to one record of a specific `ItemCode` on a specific `Date`, 
then just do a left join (see `?merge`) of the the first and second data frame on these three attributes.

Was gonna write that as a comment, but decided to write some code instead.

```
orig<-data.frame(ItemCode=c(1234,3342,2345), Invoice=c(1111,1134,1231), Quantity=c(12,2,5), 
                 Date=as.Date(c("12/11/04","14/12/04","21/12/04"), format="%d/%m/%y"),
                 UnitPrice=c(12.9,5,8.99), CustomerID = c(70829,70562,71233))
delt<-data.frame(ItemCode=c(1345,3342,2345), Invoice=rep(NA,3), Quantity=c(-10,-2,-1), 
                 Date=as.Date(c("27/02/05","14/12/04","21/12/04"), format="%d/%m/%y"),
                 UnitPrice=c(1.99,5,8.99), CustomerID = c(81728,70562,71233))
merged <- merge(orig, delt, by=c("ItemCode", "Date","CustomerID","UnitPrice"), all.x=TRUE)
merged$Quantity = ifelse(is.na(merged$Quantity.y),0,merged$Quantity.y) + merged$Quantity.x
merged[,c("ItemCode", "Date","CustomerID","Invoice.x", "UnitPrice", "Quantity",)]

  ItemCode       Date CustomerID Invoice.x Quantity
1:     1234 2004-11-12      70829      1111       12
2:     2345 2004-12-21      71233      1231        4
3:     3342 2004-12-14      70562      1134        0
```

Or with  data.table

```
require(data.table)
setDT(orig)
setDT(delt)
delt[orig,on=.(ItemCode, Date, CustomerID,UnitPrice)][,.(ItemCode, Date, CustomerID, i.Invoice, UnitPrice, Quantity=i.Quantity + ifelse(is.na(Quantity),0,Quantity) )]

ItemCode       Date CustomerID i.Invoice UnitPrice Quantity
1:     1234 2004-11-12      70829      1111     12.90       12
2:     3342 2004-12-14      70562      1134      5.00        0
3:     2345 2004-12-21      71233      1231      8.99        4
```